# Effect of raising handlebars on a fat bike

Tags: cannondale, geometry, fatbike

I am currently demoing a 2019 [Cannondale Fat Caad 2](https://www.cannondale.com/International/bike/Productdetail?Id=f55b292b-9378-4663-b386-8e2eb69d9873).  Never owned a fat bike before.  This bike is relatively light and they are on clearance right now at a local bike shop that I ride with and do business with.

The problem I am running into (and it seems to be a common complaint of this particular model) is that the front is too low.  The bike shop owner says I can raise the handlebars using a different stem and handlebars. I get that.  I've done it with my Fuji Jari and my cheap mountain bike.

But I think it would need to be a bit more extreme with this bike, and so I'd like to understand the effect from a riding perspective that this will cause.  I'm not a bike geometry expert, but I get some of the general idea.

I'll mostly be using this bike for 2 things:  Winter snow riding (not on extreme terrain) and all season all-terrain riding (not on extreme terrain).  I'm not big on technical stuff, but I like to explore and ride a bike in all weather and wherever I can.

I generally keep my center of gravity over the pedals (light on the hands) and spend a decent amount of time out of the saddle.

So my question boils down to: What effect will raising the handlebars have on how the bike will handle, and ultimately, is this a legit thing for me to do for my riding style or would I be better off looking into a different fat bike with a different geometry?

Comment: For head up, seeing the sights and exploring, i'd suggest you perhaps want a different fat bike.  It looks very much to me like Cannondale have aimed to make the Fat Caad like an XC race bike with giant tyres

Comment: Stems aren't very expensive -- especially compared to what you'd lose trading in this bike for a different one. Unless somebody comes along and explains why it would be a bad idea, it's probably worth trying it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - the shop owner just put like a 25deg stem on it. I'll see how it feels.  I haven't actually bought the bike.  He's letting me ride his demo for a few days.  I need to decide if the clearance price is worth needing to modify it, and if what I have in the end will be a geometric nightmare or something solid for me to ride.

Comment: @MikeJansen Ah, I didn't notice you were just demoing it. Makes sense.

Comment: A threadless riser adapter is one way to do it, but its another point of failure, and allows the bars to make more leverage on the stem.

Answer (score 4):

Generally fat bikes seem to have the bars at about the same height as the saddle, which the Fat Caad complies with. If you personally want the bars a little higher that's fine.

The Caad stem length is quite short so it has limited potential for raising the bars. Riser bars in conjunction with a different stem will help.